# Some keyboard keys not working after install

Tags: keyboard, ibus

The Z, X, V, M, N, right alt and left arrow keys do not work every time they are pressed and with time they stop working completely. I was having no issues with Linux Mint but now while using Mint, the problem occurs at boot but pressing any of the above keys 2 or 3 times solves the issue and the keyboard becomes responsive again. The keyboard works in BIOS. Have tried different keyboard layouts but nothing works. Please help, I really wanna use elementary.
Btw, reinstalling also does not work.